# Samsung Galaxy S III mini - Cannot turn Bluetooth on

Tags: bluetooth, hardware, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I have new Samsung Galaxy S III mini (GT-I8190N) with Android 4.1.2, and I cannot turn on Bluetooth.

When trying to do it from Settings menu, switch toggles from "O" to "I" position, but remains gray rather than green, list of available devices is empty and 'Scan' button is inative, and when going back to Settings menu I see Bluetooth turned off.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to reboot / remove battery. Maybe resetting to factory settings will help. In addition, if everything else fails, you could try following (read somewhere about it):  turn it off and then back on (the one asking you about using wifi to localize you faster) the bluetooth and wifi are both 802.11 standards, therefore they are controlled by the same chip

Comment: Rebooting phone solved the original issue with Bluetooth, and new issue with Wi-Fi not turning on which made me do reboot.